# Disconnecting Your House From Your Neighbors House

Tags: old-house

I'm buying a new house, displayed on the right in the picture below, and about 10 feet of the house in length is connected to the neighboring home, displayed on the left in the picture. I know it's hard to tell but there is an alley or whatever you call it between the two houses that you can see from the front of the house. So they aren't connected for the entire length; only about 10 feet in the back on the first floor. Also the house to the right of mine is not connected to mine even though it appears that it is in the picture.

So my question is what does this mean for me in terms of the owner of this house? If I wanted to could I legally disconnect my house from the neighboring house? Could I pay a contractor to come out and do that?

I know this sort of thing is common in the city but it just seems unsettling to me that my personal space is somewhat shared with another random person. I had a girlfriend in the past who rented a house with her friends and all three floors of the house were connected to the neighboring house and they had a bad bed bug infestation. After three unsuccessful extermination treatments the exterminators determined that the bed bugs were coming from the house next door to them that was connected. It was a wooden frame house, like mine, and not brick which wouldn't be concerning i.g., a brick row home is more of a solid boundary between neighbors.

So the concerning aspects in my mind are bugs coming over to my house from my neighbor such as bed bugs or termites, hearing noise from my neighbor in that part of the house, and to a lesser extent a fire from my neighbors house (although which such a close distance I'm sure it would travel to my house even if they weren't connected).

Am I just being paranoid about this? And if not what are my options for disconnected my house if I choose to in the future? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Since you are _buying_ the house, and haven't yet _bought_, make sure you are 100% satisfied with the answers you get to these questions **before** you sign any paperwork or hand over any money! I'm a firm believer in "it'll work out OK", but you're putting a lot of money on the line here. Ask the realtor, the bankers, everyone for help in getting answers to your questions _**BEFORE**_ you pay! Be prepared to either live with "no" if you can't separate them, or to walk away if it's that big a deal to you.

Comment: Seeing that it is attached to the neighbours, quite sure they must give their okay also, no matter what you want.  Probably need to have the outside of their house finished to their specs if they give an okay.  You want it, you pay for it deal.

Comment: Is this really a DIY question or does it need moved to law.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Can you get us more information (say from a home inspector's report) as to how the party wall between the two buildings was constructed?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yup my home inspection is this Tuesday (December 21st 2021) so I'll update here with their findings

Answer (score 4):

You are basically asking a zoning question and for the answer, you need to go to to your local planning dept and find out what the zoning destination is for your property and what that means. It may have been permitted as a duplex, a zero lot line, triplex or whatever and if so , you may be unable to reconstruct it legally. These answers could also be on the web site of your city or county and/or in your deed. Ultimately the city or county decides what type of structures can be built based on the zoning. So call and have your address handy. It may have been permitted as some type of multifamily development and is not classified as a single family home.

Comment: Ah okay that makes perfect sense and would explain why it's such a small part that's connected. Maybe they never wanted them connected in the first place but because of the zoning they had to. That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Not good news here.

Other than duplex, condo, or apartment, for fire concerns, most cities require a setback between two adjacent buildings, which shouldn't be blocked, though many people have erected gates to block thru-traffic for privacy.

In this case, the previous owner had taken one step further, upon remodeling, he added or enlarged the back porch and permanently blocked the passage. It may be in violation of the local ordinance/building code without being caught. However, you may be ordered, by the local authority, to take it down at your own expanse.

The good thing is that I don't think it is a common wall shared by the two buildings, so demolition wouldn't be difficult. If you are really interested in this house, you shall check with the seller, the neighbor, then the City, if no one has knowledge of it.

Comment: Yeah -- without that setback, you need fire rated construction on the adjacent walls, up to and including a *party wall* construction where the two buildings meet

Comment: First off let me start by saying I love your artwork lol! But very good point thank you. I have my home inspection on Tuesday (December 21st 2021) so I'll be sure to bring this up.

Comment: Also this house is in Pittsburgh and I will say that I see a lot of houses that are connected like this here so perhaps Pittsburgh is just a weird city that allows this type of thing but I definitely agree with you that I should check with the city to make sure.

Comment: [Rowhouses](https://www.thespruce.com/what-is-a-rowhouse-5180207).

Comment: @PeteBecker I am afraid it is not the case. From OP's picture, it looks like the connected part is only the back porch. It is also indicated by the OP "about 10' in the back".

Comment: @r13 -- you're reading too much into my comment.

Comment: @PeteBecker I understand that you are trying to remind us there is another name for buildings that are connected together without separation. Thanks, it did not come to my head at writing the answer.